# Alternate meaning of SqlCommand's 1st parameter

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

According to MSDN, the default meaning of the 1st parameter of SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection) is a string of that contains the query to the specified database connection such as

```
String = "INSERT INTO abc(id, name) VALUES(param1, param2)";
```

I found this in someone else's code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("rp_air_etg", sql_database_connection);
```

Does this mean "cmd" is implicitly importing query from a SQL-script?

However, I couldn't find a file with the name "rp_air_etg" anywhere in the solution or the project folder.

Comment: That is stored procedure name

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I didn't hit enter quick enough :)

Comment: @DanAndrews ha me neither =)

Comment: You will probably find that the [SqlCommand.CommandType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton not necessary - you can run stored procedure with command type Text (there is only some difference in messages buffering on server and parameter names)

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy

Does this mean the stored procedure is inside the sql database?

Comment: Okay yeah, I checked, The stored procedures are indeed stored inside the target database.

Comment: If they were not located there you'd have an exception and a completely different SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parameter is assigned to [CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which can be SQL statement, table name or stored procedure to execute at the data source. That is shown in *remarks* section of [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor - you can see that CommandText initial value is equal to *cmdText* parameter. And here is implementation:

```
public SqlCommand(string cmdText, SqlConnection connection) : this()
{
    this.CommandText = cmdText;
    this.Connection = connection;
}
```

So, in your case it is either table name or stored procedure name.